# Passing a variable from javascript using $_POST

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable from a javascript function to my php file. All I do is extract the user_name from a cookie in javascript and then use AJAX to $_POST the variable to my php file for processing. I do not use a form to submit the POST variable which I have done in the past.

The problem is my $_POST array is not getting passed to the php file. I've looked here and looked at several other suggestions but none work. Do you have to submit the $_POST variable via an html form? I dont think so but maybe I'm wrong. Here is the code:

Javascript -

```
function clearDoneItems()  {
var user_name = getNameFromCookie();

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } 
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 } 

alert(user_name);
xmlhttp.open("POST","todolist/clear_done_items.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(user_name);
displayHomeInformation(user_name);

}
```

PHP -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Clear Done Items</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
print_r($_POST);

  $xml_name=$_POST['user_name'];  
  $xml_file = $xml_name . ".xml";
  echo $xml_file;    
    /* Here we will use the The DOMDocument class functions to delete 
       the text nodes.    
       Format XML to save indented tree rather than one line */
$domxml = new DOMDocument('1.0');

if ($domxml->load('$xml_file') === TRUE) {
$domxml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$domxml->formatOutput = true;

// Start Delete process of node
echo "<br>";

$xpath = new DOMXPath($domxml);
// Here we use the The DOMXPath class function evaluate to do the heavy lifting.

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//doneitems/item') as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

//Save XML to file - remove this and following line if save not desired
$domxml->save('alan.xml');
echo "<strong>XML Document updated.</strong>";
 }

else {
echo "  <strong>Error in loading XML file:</strong>"; 
 echo "<br>";
 print_r(error_get_last());     
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

> Errors on php page:
>   Notice: Undefined index: user_name in /var/www/bb/todolist/clear_done_items.php on line 16
>   0
>   Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/var/www/bb/todolist/$xml_file" in /var/www/bb/todolist/clear_done_items.php on line 24

Comment: sidenote: `$xml_file = $xml_name + ".xml";` the `+` is a JS/C++ concatenate operator. You want to use a dot. Please edit your question with the HTML form.

Comment: Plus, if you're running your entire code that includes both HTML form and PHP, you will need to use `isset()` or `!empty()` for the POST array. Chances are, your input isn't named or there's a typo.

Comment: *"Do you have to submit the $_POST variable via an html form?"* - Many a times, yes. Where is `$_POST['user_name']` coming from?

Comment: last comment - `user_name` seems to be relying on whatever `getNameFromCookie()` is doing.

Comment: Thanks I corrected php. I thought from reading up on AJAX the POST variable is set from the three commands xmlhttp.open,.setRequestHeader and .send. Dont these take the place of the POST action in an html form?

Comment: I thought by setting the user_name variable via the cookie then I could just POST it over to my php file using xmlhttp.send and then the php would process the xml file and update it. But the POST array is empty so my logic is flawed somewhere.

Comment: Just to be clear I dont need the ".onreadystatechange" event handler if all I want is to pass the user_name to the  php script and dont need anything back form the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in responding. I just wanted to post how I solved issue. I will have to revisit using the $_POST array with AJAX cause I was never able to pass a variable thru it.

Javascript:

```
// Clear Done Items Function
function clear_done_items()
{
var xmlhttp;

var temp = document.getElementById("list_section");
var temp_list_name = temp.innerHTML;
var str_len = temp_list_name.length;
var list_name = temp_list_name.slice(17,str_len);
var user_name = getNameFromCookie();

if (user_name == list_name) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("POST","todolist/clear_done_items.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

} else {
   alert("Warning: You Must be Logged in as this User, " + list_name + ", to Delete the Completed Items List");
  }

}
```

and php:

```
<?php
$xml_cookie = $_COOKIE['user'];

$xml_file_name = $xml_cookie . ".xml";

    /* Here we will use the The DOMDocument class functions to delete
       the text nodes.*/

     //Format XML to save indented tree rather than one line
$domxml = new DOMDocument('1.0');

if ($domxml->load($xml_file_name) === TRUE) {
$domxml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$domxml->formatOutput = true;

// Start Delete process of node
echo "<br>";

$xpath = new DOMXPath($domxml);
// Here we use the The DOMXPath class function evaluate to do the heavy lifting.

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//doneitems/item') as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

//Save XML to file - remove this and following line if save not desired
$domxml->save($xml_file_name);
echo "<strong>XML Document updated.</strong>";
 }

else {
echo "  <strong>Error in loading XML file:</strong>";
 echo "<br>";
 print_r(error_get_last());

}

?>
```

so basically I'm using a cookie to get the user_name variable to php to process from the main page.